# Kernel of the geometric intersection form

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed surface and $\mathcal C$ the set of all free homotopy classes of closed (may be nonsimple) curves in $\Sigma$. Consider the geometric intersection form $i$ on $\mathbb Z\mathcal C$
$$i(\sum_p a_p x_p, \sum_q b_q y_q)=\sum_{p,q}a_pb_q i(x_p,y_q),\quad a_p,b_q\in\mathbb Z, x_p,y_q\in\mathcal C.
$$
Here $i(x_p,y_q)$ is the geometric intersection number of the curves $x_p$ and $y_q$.

Let $K=\left\{z\in\mathbb Z\mathcal C\mid \forall x\in\mathcal C\ i(z,x)=0\right\}$ be the kernel of the form $i$.

Is it true that $K$ is generated by the elements $x^n-nx$, $x\in\mathcal C$, $n\in\mathbb N$? In other words, if one restricts the geometric intersection form to the primitive curves (i.e. the curves which are not proper powers) will it become nondegenerate?